# Replacing a line of PHP using ansible

Tags: php, ansible

I am trying to remove this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context in /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/objects/client/pts_installed_test.php on line 105
```

The issue was that i am using an old version of PHP, so I had to change:

```
if($this->get_runtime_errors() && !empty($this->get_runtime_errors()))
```

to:

```
if($this->runtime_errors && !empty($this->runtime_errors))
```

I want to automatically implement this change. I wrote an ansible script:

```
- name: Make new PHP file compatable
  lineinfile:
    path: /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/objects/client/pts_installed_test.php
    regexp: 'if($this->get_runtime_errors() && !empty($this->get_runtime_errors()))'
    line: "if($this->runtime_errors && !empty($this->runtime_errors))"
    backrefs: yes
```

However even though the process reports okay, no change is implemented.

Comment: You have regexp meta characters in your regexp, so you'll want to use [`| regex_escape`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) on that parameter it to turn them back into the literal ones

Comment: Note that in this particular case, getting the actual file, fixing it locally in your preferred IDE and coping it back in place with ansible would probably be more secure and less error prone.